# how to create a class tag for to build a broadcast variable spark with java?

Tags: java, apache-spark

I need to create a borodcast in my JAVA function , a broadcast of list of string

```
Broadcast<List<String>>broadcastSp = sc.broadcast(Tvalue,classTag<T>evidence);
```

The T value is "my_list" (`List<String>)`, but the problem is how to create the  second part `classTag<T>evidence`.

Comment: my_list is a list of String

Answer (score 3):

There should be no need for that. When working in Java you shouldn't use `org.apache.spark.SparkContext`, which is designed with Scala in mind. Instead use `org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext`

To quote the official docs:

```
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext;
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;

SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("broadcast").setMaster("local[*]");
JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
```

It's broadcast method doesn't require `ClassTags` ([example from the official docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/rdd-programming-guide.html#broadcast-variables)):

```
Broadcast<int[]> broadcastVar = sc.broadcast(new int[] {1, 2, 3});
```

Comment: thank you @user10465661, but i must create the class tag , i share with you my function

Answer (score 0):

this is my function :

```
public static JavaSparkContext sc;
public static Broadcast < List < String >> broadcastP;
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    sc = new JavaSparkContext("local", "test");
    .
    .
    .
    private static List < String > fFtItemSets(JavaRDD < String > base_initiale) throws Exception {
      List < String > kMinusOneSets;
      List < String > k_sets;

      int i = 1;
      k_sets = remplir_ksets_intiale(base_initiale);
      System.out.println(k_sets);
      List < String > k_sets1 = k_sets;
      int NB = k_sets.size();
      while (NB > 1) {
        kMinusOneSets = k_sets;
        k_sets = Jointure(kMinusOneSets);

        k_sets = Elagage(k_sets, k_sets1, i);
        System.out.println(k_sets);


        Broadcast < List < String >> broadcastSp = sc.broadcast(k - sets, List < String > );
        //main.sc.broadcast(k_sets);

        System.out.println(broadcastSp.value());


        k_sets = tr_freq(k_sets, broadcastnSp, base_initiale, i);
        k_sets1 = k_sets;
        NB++;
        i++;

      }
      return k_sets;
    }
```

Comment: the problem is in the part of :Broadcast<List<String>> broadcastSp=sc.broadcast(k-sets,classTag);

Comment: If you want to add new information to your question use the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52678758/edit) link. The answer should be used only for actual answers.